# Плановое техническое обслуживание 17/18 апреля 2019 года в 00:00 по UTC (03:00 по Москве, GMT+3)

Tags: обсуждение, объявления

**tl; dr**: плановые работы затронут все сайты сети Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange, чат и SO for Teams. Все сайты будут доступны только в режиме чтения в течение часа во время обслуживания. Корпоративные инстансы затронуты не будут.

## Короткая версия

На следующей неделе будут проблемы с доступом на срок до одного часа - возможно, 17 или 18 апреля 2019 года в 00:00 по UTC (03:00 по Москве, GMT+3). В течение этого времени вопросы и ответы будут отображаться.

**Тем не менее, сайт будет «только на чтение», то есть нельзя будет авторизоваться, нельзя будет создавать, редактировать или голосовать по вопросам/комментариям/ответам, не будет изменений репутации и т. д.**

Это должно свести к минимуму сбои для большинства читателей. Мы будем показывать баннер на сайтах, говорящий, что мы «работаем в режиме чтения» на время технического обслуживания. Мы ожидаем, что сайт будет находиться в этом режиме не более часа.

## Более подробная информация и технические детали

[Planned maintenance scheduled April 17/18, 2019 at 00:00UTC (8:00pm US/Eastern)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326718/260198)

Comment: @Nicolas уже пора о [новом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326718/339911) писать, а здесь красную метку долой.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Спасибо! Убрал метку.